# Icons not showing on my my External Drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, icons

**My friend could change icons on his external drive. I cant on mine though for some reason.**

**Question 1:**
I make extensive use of custom icons on my computer.
My icons are not working on my external drive though.
I think this has to do with user rights?
Because everything i do on my external drive i get asked for administrator permissions.
**I am using the Main account.**

I noticed that when i press F5 on my external drive.
I dont really see any refreshing happening

And when i change the user permissions.
They always get set back to default after taking it out and back in.

.

**Question 2:**

[image]

Sorry for doing 2 questions in 1. Hope thats ok.

Comment: May be try the thumbnail cache clear and reset and see or you may try a quick rebuild of icon cache to generate the previews rightly it may work sometimes.

Comment: Just did that. Did not work unfortunately. Also whats crucial. my icons work on my C drive but not my External one.

Comment: Thank you mureinik. I did not have enough points to use images it said. So thats why i used a hyperlink ^^

Answer (score 0):

sorry for misunderstanding.if you want to change folder icon inside external HDD,you may try to use relative path:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=\any_folder\icons\my_icon.ico,0
```

And you have to keep few things in mind it should be system file and hidden.if you have created `desktop.ini` with notepad it will not work.
to make it work you have to apply few attribute with `cmd`:

```
attrib path_to\desktop.ini +s +r -a
```

and folder itself also,

```
attrib folder +r
```

i have tested in win8.1.if it not works please give information regarding windows version,filesystem,etc.And also check for viruses and bugs in your windows.

Comment: What i do is i first pick a normal icon (which also does not show up) and then i edit the .ini file. to make it local. and that still does not work. i think it has to do with permissions. because for everything it needs administrator rights constantly

Comment: i have tried in my external hdd and done several experiments with permission.but in my case every time it worked fine.have you tried in other external hdd or flash.

Comment: I have not no. Thinking about ordering a new HDD so i can atleast do a double backup and format the one that is not showing icons. thats the next plan. Currently i screwed up allot by removing something in regedit that someone advised me to do.

Comment: ok , i'm not telling you to buy new hdd friend.if your friend or relative has one.if not why don't you try any pendrive.you may also backup and format your hdd.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i did not mean to say that you said that. It was just an idea i had. Because i think its my HDD so i think it needs to be formatted. But right now i cant format the HDD because it already has stuff on it. And i dont have space to swaperoo things heh ^^